# GetDeviceDriverBaseName to find a specific driver

Tags: c++, windows, device-driver

I am rather new to kernel things so I figured I would learn how to find a device driver by name in C++. I'm stumped as I don't really understand the way to use `GetDeviceDriverBaseName` to get a specific driver name out of it. I also couldn't really find tutorials or docs besides the ones from Microsoft.

Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <psapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "Title.h"

#define ARRAY_SIZE 1024

int main( void ) 
{   
    LPVOID drivers[ARRAY_SIZE];
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    int cDrivers, i;
    if (EnumDeviceDrivers(drivers, sizeof(drivers), &cbNeeded) && cbNeeded < sizeof(drivers))
    {
        TCHAR szDriver[ARRAY_SIZE];
        cDrivers = cbNeeded / sizeof(drivers[0]);
        _tprintf(TEXT("There are %d drivers:\n"), cDrivers);
        for (i = 0; i < cDrivers; i++)
        {
            if (GetDeviceDriverBaseName(drivers[i], szDriver, sizeof(szDriver) / sizeof(szDriver[0])))
            {
                _tprintf(TEXT("%d: %s\n"), i + 1, szDriver);
            }
        }
    }
    
    else
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Enumeration of Drivers failed; array size need is %d\n"), cbNeeded / sizeof(LPVOID));
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the reference code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-device-drivers-in-the-system), but with `#include <windows.h>` missing, and this comment cut off: "*To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS and compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1*". Did you do that, and if so what's not working?

Comment: The issue is not that I am missing a header file I have windows.h in there I just forgot to put in on this post. The issue is that my goal is to try to make a user mode c++ application that can tell me if a specific driver is currently loaded. I have no idea how to do that. The current code tells me every driver but not a specific one. That is my issue filtering/singling a specific driver by the name out of that array

Comment: If the question is how to find a given string in the list of strings that was returned, then just `strcmp` the string you are looking for against each string in the list.

Comment: im going to try this ive personally never used strcmp and im ready to do so thank you for the response.